# Referential integrity on UNION or VIEW

Tags: sql-server, referential-integrity

I already saw similar open issues, but my situation is slightly different.

I have several tables which reference the same key value pair (a small integer and a string code). I want to build one table which accepts all these references from the different parent tables.

Say, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE keyValuePair 
(
   idx SMALLINT,
   kvValue CHAR(4)
   ...
 )

CREATE TABLE entity1 
(
  entity1ID INT ...
)

CREATE TABLE entity2 
(
  entity2ID INT ...
)
```

...

```
CREATE TABLE entityN 
(
  entityNID INT ...
)


CREATE TABLE allReferences 
(
   entityType TINYINT,
   entityID INT,
   kvIdx SMALLINT,
   kvVal CHAR(4)
   ...
)
```

The question is, how do I create referential integrity in allReferences to make sure that upon deleting either an `entity1` or `entity2` row all their children in `allReferences` will be deleted?

Do I have to create triggers instead?

Comment: @Elliveny, what does it have to do with my question at all?

Comment: Can you do it the other way? Create foreign keys in entity1, entity2 tables on entityID (and entityType if needed).So, when you delete row from allReferences table, rows in entity1, entity2 tables will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks @Swapnil. It's problematic because it's the entity1 and entity2 etc. are being updated. If I have to manually update their children, why bother with referential integrity at all? The only upside would be making sure there are no orphans. I'd rather go with triggers.

Comment: @Vadim - apologies, I should have studied the question a little more before commenting. I've now deleted my previous comment.

Comment: I would have one column per possible FK in `allReferences` and a check constraint to ensure that exactly one of them is populated. And/or reconsider whether `allReferences` really should exist, whether `keyValuePair` is really shared between all possible entities, and whether the multiple entities should actually all be modelled as a single table. But the question's too abstract currently to say whether any of these later options *should* be taken.

Comment: @VadimBerman: I also think you wil need to with triggers. Another thought is to replace allReferences table by a view or indexed view.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: one column per entity defeats the purpose, then I would split it and keep a separate child table per entity. The problem is, there will be over ten so it's a hassle. Yes, `allReferences` should exist as `keyValuePair` is more of a dictionary of possible values and not their instances per entities.

Comment: @Swapnil: the point is to reduce maintenance, hence merging everything. If I had separate tables, I'd simply add the foreign key normally. It's just their sheer quantity that bogs me down.

Comment: @VadimBerman: As result of indexed view is stored in database, if you replace allReferences by indexed view on union of all entity tables, it might give you the performace close the actual table.

Comment: @Swapnil: but since I still need to add foreign keys, what do I gain over a situation where `allReferences` **is** an actual table?

Comment: @VadimBerman: You will not need foreign key if you use indexed view.If a record is deleted from entity table, it will not appear in view.Another approach: create foreign keys in 'entity tables' as well as 'allReferences' table that refer to 'keyValuePair' table. Perform delete operation 'keyValuePair ' table which delete records from all children.

Comment: @Swapnil: thanks for all the ideas, and I hate to be the princess on the pea, but sadly, no... My needs are the opposite. The reason I'm pushing everything into one table is not to create the ten plus special 1:n tables. keyValuePair is the "dictionary", of course it will delete everything, but what is it going to achieve?

Comment: @VadimBerman: Problem mentioned in the question is called "Polymorphic Associations" i.e. the "foreign key" column contains an id value that must exist in one of a set of target tables. There's no way to implement it using SQL constraints. I am interested to know if someone can explain how to achieve it. :)

Comment: @Swapnil: which is why I asked this question. For now the only way to solve it is a trigger, or creating a bazillion small tables, of course.